# Bluetooth incoming data string distortion

Tags: vba, bluetooth, distortion

I have scales equipped with RS232 serial port and a Bluetooth transmitter. I made a program in VBA to receive data from the scales. However, lets say out of 10 incoming strings I get 3 distorted. My regular strings look like: "+001500./3 G S". This means 1500.3 grams above zero and the output is stable. But sometimes I get strings like separated like "+" or "001500./3" or "G S". When I plug serial cable I have no distortions.

Answer (score 0):

Serial ports are just byte streams.  You can never make assumptions about how many of the bytes will show up on each read operation.  It's only coincidence that when you use a real cable you read the whole string at once.  You have to do the string splitting yourself, and continue reading when you only get a partial result.